# iOS- How to add buttons above UISplitViewController Detail View

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

i am working on use UISplitViewController where the left side shows the menu and the right shows the detail view.

I want to be able to add buttons above the detail view(the 3 buttons on the right side of the screen) like the picture below:
[image]

**--EDITED--**

So my questions are:

1. How do I add buttons above the detail view like the above picture?
2. When the button is tapped, how to show a new screen where users are allowed to key in information.

Comment: On click of button use [self presentViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#> completion:<#^(void)completion#>] method for presenting a different viewconroller over it.

Comment: sorry maybe i wasn't clear. How do i add those buttons above detail view controller?

Answer (score 2):

1.**The best way is to use the `navigationBar` of your `detailViewController` and add `UIBarButtonItems`**

> It goes like this:

In your `DetailViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` add three `barButtonItems`.

As your image holds image for the button the below code is used to create `barButtonItem` with image.

```
UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1st button image"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(yourActionMethod)];
UIBarButtonItem *button2 =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2nd button image"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(yourActionMethod)];
UIBarButtonItem *button3 =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3rd button image"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(yourActionMethod)];
```

Then we add the button to the `navigationItem` of our `DetailViewController` like:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[button1,button2,button3];
```

2.Now when the Button is tapped the `action:@Selector(yourActionMethod)` gets called, from there we can show the new screen.

> Lets Dive into the code Shall we . . .

To show the new screen we can use the `splitViewController`'s:

```
- (void)showDetailViewController:(UIViewController *)vc sender:(nullable id)sender NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

Our function / Method block will look like this

```
-(void)yourActionMethod{

UIViewController * yourNewViewController =  //load your view controller here 

[self showDetailViewController:yourNewViewController sender:self];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply create UIBarButton and add functionality of presenting your other VC over your current splitVC as your using a navigation bar.

```
UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"delete" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(youfunction1)];
UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"delete" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(youfunction2)];
UIBarButtonItem *item3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"delete" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(youfunction3)];

self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[item1,item2,item3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add button directly on the UIViewController storyboard file and connect there event to the controller.If you want to open the new screen for Add Record then you can create one controller and present it from there.

*

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

*

aMethod will be called and you can create your controller object here and present it.

Comment: hi. i'm not working with storyboard. i programmatically created the UISplitViewController

Comment: hi what is view in [view addSubview:button]? should i be adding the button to UISplitViewController barButtonItem instead?

Comment: View is your controller view.UISplitViewController have two .viewControllers so add this lines to the second controller viewDidLoad